# Why the browser display the entity name?

Tags: python, html, web.py

```
import urllib2
url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/hot.json"
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'super happy flair bot by /u/spladug' }
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
data = '{0}({1})'.format("callback", html)
print data
```

I want to use some data scraped from some sites and make the return value support the JSONP.But the browser outputs:

```
callback({&quot;kind&quot;: &quot;Listing&quot;, &quot;data&quot;:........
```

Actually I want:

callback({"kind": "Listing", "data":........

I don't want the quotes convert to `&quot;`.Maybe I should not use function read(),but I don't know how to deal with it?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that your entire program? Because, when I run your program (as `python his_program.py`), it prints the text that you want.

Comment: *Aside*: Your `import json` is superfluous; you never parse the json object.

Comment: Finally: You say, "*But the browser outputs ...*"  How is the program you posted connected to a web browser?

Comment: @Robᵩ This is my [url](http://southmoneyweixin.sinaapp.com/callback#).I use webpy framework to handle this.

Comment: @Robᵩ Maybe it's a encoding error,but I still can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: The program you posted works perfectly. Please try to create a short test case that demonstrates the problem. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information. Meanwhile, I've added a `web.py` tag so that web.py experts can take a look.

Comment: @Robᵩ Are you sure it works well?My chrome displays the quotes with &quot;

Comment: The program, when run from the command line, works perfectly. If you want us to debug running it from web.py, you'll need to provide an example for that.